# magento 2 shopping cart problem

Tags: magento2, checkout

Currently I have my store in magento 2.2.7 from the beginning I configure an API to present amazon and waltmart products, so far everything is ok, but now it is required that magento own products be uploaded, they are created without problem, but at the moment Adding them to the cart gets the error "We cannot add this item to your shopping cart at this time." This work was done by an expert in magento, I am a newbie, where I can see the configuration of the cart for review

Comment: Please enable developer mode using the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer` to log errors and after that check the var/log folder if the error message logged to file.

Comment: Hi, let me tell you that I don't get the error, it's weird!